# How to sum values over timeperiod in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

What is wrong with my `SUMIFS`? I would like to sum up all the values between two points in time. I have added a "Want" column to my screenshot to show what I am looking for.

The expression looks like this:

> =SUMMEWENNS(B:B;A:A;"<="&D7;A:A;">="&D8)

(sorry, german Excel, that's just SUMIFS)

Since I don't know how to insert tables here is a screenshot of the data:
[image: data screenshot]

So basically for every point in time I want to sum up all the values until the next point...
Here is the data in csv in case you want to try it out yourself:

```
Time;Amount;;Time;;Want
2015-07-07 11:00;12;;1900-01-00 00:00;0;34
2015-07-07 17:00;22;;2015-07-07 18:00;0;87
2015-07-07 22:00;10;;2015-07-08 12:00;0;2
2015-07-08 03:00;34;;2015-07-08 16:00;13;0
2015-07-08 09:00;43;;2015-07-09 00:00;0;13
2015-07-08 15:00;2;;2015-07-10 00:00;0;
2015-07-09 01:00;8;;;;
2015-07-09 12:00;2;;;;
2015-07-09 23:00;3;;;;
;136;;;13;136
```

Revision:
Okay, I tried your solution and I am still mucking something up.
Where is the 30 in this coming from? :)
That's the formula for that specific line:

```
=SUMMEWENNS(test!B:B;test!A:A;">="&D4;test!A:A;"<"&D5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the ">" and "<" signs be reversed?.....and to avoid possible double counting only one should have `=`. Try this formula in row 2 copied down

`=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;">="&D2;A:A;"<"&D3)`

Comment: Wow, that does indeed do excatly what I want. I have no idea how I looked at it so many times and rewrote it from scratch twice and always got that wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up: Why do I get 13 when I mix up the rules? If A>B how is there a C with C>A AND B>C?

Comment: Yes, I can't account for that - if your formula is consistent you'd get all zeroes - perhaps some of the column D values are text strings rather than real time/dates?

Comment: Would you mind taking a look? http://www.expirebox.com/download/5708eb8e2a7e5a85bd670c93aad8e000.html

Comment: Okay, when I try this in libreoffice calc it works. Any other place I could ask about this?

Comment: It does not seem to work even in the case when the condition is correct.

Comment: I've opened a new question for the other problem: https://superuser.com/questions/937727/how-does-sumifs-relate-to-sumproduct